# Override fooman order contrioller

Tags: adminhtml

i am override fooman extension in community my folder path
 community/Fooman/OrderManager/Sales/controllers/OrederManager.php 
i override my folder local/Mymoduel/PrintPdf/Sales/controllers/OrderMangerController.php and this is my config 
 
  
      
              
               
                  Mymodues_PrintPdf 
   
 
 
 –

and this is fooman community config  
  
        
         
           Fooman_OrderManager

Comment: Please edit your original question instead of making a new one

Comment: we can not override dulipcate? this is my community code config <modules>
                        <Fooman_OrderManager before="Mage_Adminhtml">Fooman_OrderManager</Fooman_OrderManager>
                    </modules>